# Что лучше использовать using std:: или остоянно приписывать std::?

Tags: c++, рефакторинг

Слышал, что в C++ не следует использовать `using namespace std`.
В связи с этим вопрос, как лучше делать?
В начале программы написать:

```
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
и т.д.
```

Или перед каждым оператором писать `std::` на протяжении всей программы, то есть:

```
std::cout<<"Text"<<std::endl;
```

Интересует прежде всего с точки зрения скорости работы программы и занимаевого ею места.

Comment: [связанный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/2881286)

Comment: Найдите дубликат, кто-нибудь!

Comment: @VladD, лентяй :-)

Comment: Если говорят, что нельзя, то обязательно нужно разобраться - почему именно!
Нежелательно так делать в заголовочных файлах потому, что это повлияет на все файлы, куда они подключаются. *Даже те, которые будут написаны в будущем.* И если вдруг появится конфликт пространств имен, то придется как-то это разруливать сразу везде, а это будет куча работы и новых багов.

Если же вы напишите `using` внутри исходника (`*.cpp`), то всё самое страшное ограничится лишь одним этим файлом. Поэтому внутри спокойно используйте `using`, делайте код читабельным!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С точки зрения работы/занимаемого места - разницы никакой, ибо для компилятора это одно и то же.

С точки зрения стоит/не стоит - старайтесь не использовать `using` в заголовочных файлах. В файлах с реализацией вполне нормально использовать `using`, если кода там не супермного.

Answer (score 0):

ИМХО. Лучше везде писать `std::` и другие конкретные неймспэйсы, если программа использует не только стандартные библиотеки. Ну типа программы "Hello world")) Но ведь тогда уже можно писать `using namespace std;` А если нет, то даже если в сторонних библиотеках имена не пересекутся, то вы сами можете случайно написать какой-нибудь тип данных или создать объект, название которого совпадет с чем-нибудь из подключенной библиотеки. А вариант `using std::cin, using std::cout;`, как по мне, вообще странный. Откуда знать, что именно эти имена не совпадут? А если несколько разработчиков работают над программой? Чтобы совсем исключить вариант совпадения имен лучше везде конкретно указывать какому пространству принадлежит данное имя. Ну так проще. ИМХО. Ну а компилятору вообще все равно, на размере файла это не скажется, а уж на производительности тем более.